in Flutter how to Dissmiss the context menu of SPdfViewer when the specific text is selected?
enter image description herei would like to hide this default  context menu of SfPdfViewer which provided by 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/pdfviewer.dart' and don't want to be showed when the user select a specific word. Anyone has any idea how to do it ?
a solitoun of the issue or problem that iam facing now

this context menu provided only by latest version of 'syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer'. So basically i solved it quickly to change my package version to less version which is appropriate to my sdk version. Thank you all by the way. And also if anyone still has an idea how to remove it please share it with us. Thank you too much.

In Syncfusion Flutter PDF viewer, you can hide the default context menu using the canShowTextSelectionMenu API in the package version 26.1.35.
UG link: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf-viewer/text-selection#customize-the-visibility-of-the-text-selection-context-menu
